# Pandas cuts off empty columns from csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have the csv file that have columns with no content just headers. And I want them to be included to resulting DataFrame but pandas cuts them off by default. Is there any way to solve this by using read_csv not read_excell?

Comment: Please add a reproducible example, or a code snippet highlighting what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you need `header=None`:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = """
not_header_1,not_header_2
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=',')
print(df)
```

`OUTPUT:`

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [not_header_1, not_header_2]
Index: []
```

Now, `with header=None`

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=',', header=None)
print(df)
```

`OUTPUT:`

```
              0             1
0  not_header_1  not_header_2
```